# Does anko logger library log message in debug build or signed build also

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-logging, anko

I am trying to use `anko` commons library for logging debug message on logcat. I want to display logging message in debug build not in signed build. I know I can remove logging in signed builds using `Proguard` also.

I want to know if `anko` library itself log messages only in case of debug build ? OR it does in signed build also ?

Here is the `Logger` utility of `anko` library https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/d5a526512b48c5cd2e3b8f6ff14b153c2337aa22/anko/library/static/commons/src/Logging.kt

```
/**
 * Send a log message with the [Log.DEBUG] severity.
 * Note that the log message will not be written if the current log level is above [Log.DEBUG].
 * The default log level is [Log.INFO].
 *
 * @param message the function that returns message text to log.
 *   `null` value will be represent as "null", for any other value the [Any.toString] will be invoked.
 *
 * @see [Log.d].
 */
inline fun AnkoLogger.debug(message: () -> Any?) {
    val tag = loggerTag
    if (Log.isLoggable(tag, Log.DEBUG)) {
        Log.d(tag, message()?.toString() ?: "null")
    }
}
```

Do I need to remove logging using proguard ? or using some `BuildConfig.kt` or `anko` library manages itself ?

Comment: Your message will be logged only if the logging level for the given tag is explicitly set to DEBUG, regardless the build is a debug or signed one, but consider that your users won't have that setting turned on. I suggest you to check what `Log.isLoggable` does.

Comment: @rciovati Thanks. Can you please make it answer so I can accept it